# What is the format to send an NSDictionary on an HTTP Post?

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, nsdictionary, nsurlsession

I have this structure in a web service:

```
{
    "user":
    {
        "email":"prueba@hotmail.com",
        "password":"12345678",
        "objectId":"2334jklwf",
        "token":"12334023ijrdadfsdoifj"
    }
}
```

I need to make an `HTTP POST` using `NSURLSession` (iOS 9). So I need to create a dictionary with a key called `'user'` and inside that key another dictionary with all the keys shown, right? And what is the way to `POST` it?

Comment: you are using Obj-c ?

Answer (score 0):

Following function works for me you can try with it. You can set `header values` in `NSURLSessionConfiguration` object.

```
- (void)callWS {

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your URL"];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration * config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession * session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    NSDictionary * dicData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"prueba@hotmail.com",@"email",@"12345678",@"password",@"2334jklwf",@"objectId", nil];


    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"user": dicData};
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary
                                                   options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    if (!error) {

        NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                                   fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {

                                                                       // Handle response here
                                                                   }];

        [uploadTask resume];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can set json at body of request

```
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            if let data = param?.JsonStringWithPrettyPrint(){
                request.HTTPBody = NSString(string: data).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            }
```

In there: param is your dictionary 
and JsonStringWithPrettyPrint is a extentsion of NSDictionary:

```
extension NSDictionary  {
    func JsonStringWithPrettyPrint()-> String? {
        do{
            let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
            return NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String
        }catch{
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```